# C++ monad library

Tags: c++, haskell, monads

Does anyone know of a good monad template library in C++. Perhaps, one that provides some of the common monads that you would see in Haskell like Maybe.

Comment: Actually, C++ template meta-programming is a pure functional language like Haskell.

Comment: Really in this case I am just intending to play around.  It may be that there are no good uses of monads in C++.  I do not know that yet and I was hoping that I could look at the work of others before I began my own experiments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check out the "monad.h" header in FC++.
You can read more about this in the "Monads" part of this page: http://people.cs.umass.edu/~yannis/fc++/New1.5/lambda.html#monad

However, this may not be suited to actual industrial use -- it's still a nice exercise to implement and use them in C++ though.

Comment: Thank you. This is the sort of thing I was looking for.  It is not important that it be "industrial quality."  In this case I am just playing;-)

Answer (score 5):

Something like Maybe can be found in [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Actually boost optional is not really a monad. It doesn't present the right interface. I once wrote an adapter for boost:: foreach to make it work with optional. That was before I knew anything about monads but as boost foreach doesn't provide a return value its still not the complete interface for monads but pretty close.