# Express general monadic interface (like Monad class) in C++

Tags: c++, haskell, monads

Is it even possible to express a sort of monad" C++ ?
I started to write something like this, but stuck:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename  a, typename b> struct M;

template <typename a, typename b> struct M {
    virtual M<b>& operator>>( M<b>& (*fn)(M<a> &m, const a &x) ) = 0;
};

template <typename a, typename b> 
struct MSome : public M<a> {
    virtual M<b>& operator>>( M<a>& (*fn)(M<a> &m, const a &x) ) {
        return fn(*this, x);
    }

private:
    a x;
};

M<int, int>& wtf(M<int> &m, const int &v) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return m;
}

int main() {
//    MSome<int> v;
//    v >> wtf >> wtf;
    return 0;
}
```

but faced the lack of polymorphism. Actually it may be my uncurrent C++ 'cause I used it last time 8 years ago. May be it possible to express general monadic interface using some new C++ features, like type inference. It's just for fun and for explaining monads to non-haskellers and non-mathematicians.

Comment: At first sight, you'll get better results if you treat the monadic functions as classes with an `operator()()` (also more modern C++ idiomatic). This can be parameterized by the type the monadic type is accepting, so the class will accept `<T>` as template argument, and use the types `T` and `M<T>`.

Comment: but is it even possible to implement a realistic monadic function (a -> m b) without polymorphism by a and b ? And how to express this sort of polymorphism without, say, void* ? Is it possible somehow?

Comment: C++' type system is not powerful enough to abstract over higher-kinded types, but since templates are duck-typed you may ignore this and just implement various Monads seperately and then express the monadic operations as SFINAE templates. Ugly, but the best it gets.

Comment: Googling "monads in c++" turns up a few results, e.g. [this](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2011/07/11/monads-in-c/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448162/c-monad-library) (which eventually leads to [this ridiculously feature-complete implementation](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~yannis/fc++/New1.5/lambda.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C++' type system is not powerful enough to abstract over higher-kinded types, but since templates are duck-typed you may ignore this and just implement various Monads seperately and then express the monadic operations as SFINAE templates. Ugly, but the best it gets.

This comment is bang on the money. Time and time again I see people trying to make template specializations 'covariant' and/or abuse inheritance. For better or for worse, concept-oriented generic programming is in my opinion* saner. Here's a quick demo that will use C++11 features for brevity and clarity, although it should be possible to implement the same functionality in C++03:

(*: for a competing opinion, refer to "Ugly, but the best it gets" in my quote!)

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// SFINAE utility
template<typename...> struct void_ { using type = void; };
template<typename... T> using Void = typename void_<T...>::type;

/*
 * In an ideal world std::result_of would just work instead of all that.
 * Consider this as a write-once (until std::result_of is fixed), use-many
 * situation.
 */    
template<typename Sig, typename Sfinae = void> struct result_of {};
template<typename F, typename... Args>
struct result_of<
    F(Args...)
    , Void<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...))>
> {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...));
};
template<typename Sig> using ResultOf = typename result_of<Sig>::type;

/*
 * Note how both template parameters have kind *, MonadicValue would be
 * m a, not m. We don't whether MonadicValue is a specialization of some M<T>
 * or not (or derived from a specialization of some M<T>). Note that it is
 * possible to retrieve the a in m a via typename MonadicValue::value_type
 * if MonadicValue is indeed a model of the proper concept.
 *
 * Defer actual implementation to the operator() of MonadicValue,
 * which will do the monad-specific operation
 */
template<
    typename MonadicValue
    , typename F
    /* It is possible to put a self-documenting assertion here
       that will *not* SFINAE out but truly result in a hard error
       unless some conditions are not satisfied -- I leave this out
       for brevity
    , Requires<
        MonadicValueConcept<MonadicValue>
        // The two following constraints ensure that
        // F has signature a -> m b
        , Callable<F, ValueType<MonadicValue>>
        , MonadicValueConcept<ResultOf<F(ValueType<MonadicValue>)>>
    >...
    */
>
ResultOf<MonadicValue(F)>
bind(MonadicValue&& value, F&& f)
{ return std::forward<MonadicValue>(value)(std::forward<F>(f)); }

// Picking Maybe as an example monad because it's easy
template<typename T>
struct just_type {
    using value_type = T;

    // Encapsulation omitted for brevity
    value_type value;

    template<typename F>
    // The use of ResultOf means that we have a soft contraint
    // here, but the commented Requires clause in bind happens
    // before we would end up here
    ResultOf<F(value_type)>
    operator()(F&& f)
    { return std::forward<F>(f)(value); }
};

template<typename T>
just_type<T> just(T&& t)
{ return { std::forward<T>(t) }; }

template<typename T>
just_type<typename std::decay<T>::type> make_just(T&& t)
{ return { std::forward<T>(t) }; }

struct nothing_type {
    // Note that because nothing_type and just_type<T>
    // are part of the same concept we *must* put in
    // a value_type member type -- whether you need
    // a value member or not however is a design
    // consideration with trade-offs
    struct universal { template<typename T> operator T(); };
    using value_type = universal;

    template<typename F>
    nothing_type operator()(F const&) const
    { return {}; }
};
constexpr nothing_type nothing;
```

It is then possible to write something like `bind(bind(make_just(6), [](int i) { return i - 2; }), [](int i) { return just("Hello, World!"[i]); })`. Be aware that the code in this post is incomplete in that the wrapped values aren't forwarded properly, there should be errors as soon as `const`-qualified and move-only types are involved. You can see the code in action (with GCC 4.7) [here](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=71fb036a9a809e41345f8a5ba0be5696), although that might be a misnomer as all it does is not trigger assertions. ([Same code on ideone](http://ideone.com/BbVnS1) for future readers.)

The core of the solution is that none of `just_type<T>`, `nothing_type` or `MonadicValue` (inside `bind`) are monads, but are types for some monadic values of an overarching monad -- `just_type<int>` and `nothing_type` *together* are a monad (sort of -- I'm putting aside the matter of kind right now, but keep in mind that it's possible to e.g. rebind template specializations after the fact, like for `std::allocator<T>`!). As such `bind` has to be somewhat lenient in what it accepts, but notice how that doesn't mean it must accept everything.

It is of course perfectly possible to have a class template `M` such that `M<T>` is a model of `MonadicValue` and `bind(m, f)` only ever has type `M<U>` where `m` has type `M<T>`. This would in a sense make `M` the monad (with kind `* -> *`), and the code would still work. (And speaking of `Maybe`, perhaps adapting `boost::optional<T>` to have a monadic interface would be a good exercise.)

The astute reader would have noticed that I don't have an equivalent of `return` here, everything is done with the `just` and `make_just` factories which are the counterparts to the `Just` constructor. This is to keep the answer short -- a possible solution would be to write a `pure` that does the job of `return`, and that returns a value that is implicitly convertible to any type that models `MonadicValue` (by deferring for instance to some `MonadicValue::pure`).

There are design considerations though in that the limited type deduction of C++ means that `bind(pure(4), [](int) { return pure(5); })` would not work out of the box. It is not, however, an insurmountable problem. (Some outlines of a solution are to overload `bind`, but that's inconvenient if we add to the interface of our `MonadicValue` concept since any new operation must also be able to deal with pure values explicitly; or to make a pure value a model of `MonadicValue` as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
template<class T>
class IO {
public:
   virtual T get() const=0;
};

template<class T, class K>
class C : public IO<K> {
public:
   C(IO<T> &io1, IO<K> &io2) : io1(io1), io2(io2) { }
   K get() const { 
      io1.get();
      return io2.get();
   }
private:
  IO<T> &io1;
  IO<K> &io2;
};

int main() {
  IO<float> *io = new YYYY;
  IO<int> *io2 = new XXX;
  C<float,int> c(*io, *io2);
  return c.get();
}
```

Comment: Your `get()` operation is not monadic (it's actually a comonadic operation). You need to provide a `bind()` operation (which you appear to be trying to do inside your `get()` implementation... but the result from `io1` should then be provided to `io2`), and a `pure()` operation (usually called `return`, but obviously that's a keyword in C++). Or you could provide a `fmap()` and a `join()` instead of `bind()`.

Comment: No the get() is completely hidden from the user. Should only use C's constructor. only main() will need to call get().